# How to understand ただ一度きり

Tags: usage

I know that ただ一度 and 一度きり both mean "only once". However, does the expression ただ一度きり have any special meaning (my feeling is that it doesn't sound like good grammar normally)? My intuition is that it's just added emphasis.

Answer (score -1):

"Only just once" is a bad English?

Comment: Well, it does sound suspiciously like bad grammar to me. But people seem to use it (informally) anyway.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question...?